# Do any countries beside the US prohibit the sale of Kinder Surprise eggs?

Tags: united-states, trade

Kinder Surprise eggs have been banned for years in the US and since 1997 it is illegal to even bring them into the US when purchased abroad.

Are there other countries that have taken this step of completely banning the product from import?

[Wikipedia entry about Kinder Surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinder_Surprise)

[Product Website](http://www.ferrero.com/products/the-most-famous-products/kinder-surprise/surprise-play-chocolate/)

Comment: You might do well to explain what Kinder Surprise eggs are, and why they might be banned.

Comment: @SamIam - That is what the link above does - I am not going to attempt to Opine about actual reasons for banning them.  Just that they are and does anyone else do so.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a good question for this site.  The only tangential relationship to politics is that they have been used in some ads for the gun control debate.

Comment: I'd have thought "Which governments ban X?" would be on topic for politics, so long as it's asking from a curiosity standpoint.

Comment: @JNK - governmental regulation of commerce is a political thing, IMHO

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if any went to a ban (as far as I know, none did), but there was an (unsuccessful) movement in UK to ban them either in UK proper or EU wide (the Wiki link discusses the details).

Interestingly enough, according to Wiki, some company managed to figure out how to make a version of kindersurprise that is legal to import into US, but somehow separating 2 egg halves so it doesn't fall under "pieces fully enclosed into chocolate" definition.

Comment: Yes, it's called "Kinder Joy", and has the toy compartment separate from the chocolate compartment.

Answer (score 2):

[Chile banned Kinder Surprise in 2016.](http://www.dw.com/en/the-evil-egg-chile-bans-kinder-surprise/a-19362518)  Not because of a choking hazard, but as part of a general restriction on using “toys, accessories, incentives or other similar items” as a means of promoting foods that don't meet certain nutritional requirements.  The same law also affects McDonald’s Happy Meal toys.

Comment: While it is another ban I don't think it is what was being looked for in the question.